# Is there a better alternative to this Ruby idiom?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, idioms

I'm finding myself writing this bit of code in my controllers a lot:

```
params[:task][:completed_at] = Time.parse(params[:task][:completed_at]) if params[:task][:completed_at]
```

Don't get hung up on what I'm doing here specifically, because the reasons change every time; but there are many circumstances where I need to check for a value in params and change it before handing it off to `create` or `update_attributes`.

Repeating `params[:task][:completed_at]` three times feels very bad. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you changing your parameter values?  I ask that in the general sense, as well as for this specific example.

Comment: This isn't really answering your question, but this seems like the type of thing that should happen in a `before_create` or `before_save` on the model side. It will also look a bit prettier because you won't have all of the `params[:task]` business.

Comment: @DougR: that fixing-up means that the model gets its attribute value as the expected type, which means the hash can be passed directly into #create(). As pointed out, it need not be done in a controller, however.

Comment: @DougR: most commonly when I need to do something server-side that I don't want exposed to the client. An example would be user-stamping a model before save: the model can't do it, because it can't see current_user, so I have to do it automatically in the controller to prevent someone maliciously changing the associated user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to shorten this slightly is:

```
if c = params[:task][:completed_at]
  params[:task][:completed_at] = Time.parse(c)
end
```

Or, you might prefer this:

```
params[:task][:completed_at] &&= Time.parse(params[:task][:completed_at])
```

In the second case, the assignment will only happen if the left side is "truthy".

Comment: `&&=` is particularly awesome. Never seen that before. Though, at first, it is kind of funky looking.

Comment: I've never seen it either! It just occurred to me that it would work.

Comment: I haven't seen &&= used like this either. I wonder if there's something wrong with it, or no-one's thought of it before?

Comment: For some reason `&&` operations with non-boolean values makes my brain hurt, which is no wonder why I didn't think of this. I even use the `||=` idiom all the time. Very cool.

Comment: I think `||=` is pretty standard (assigns if the left-hand side is "falsy"), so I'd be fairly confident that this works as expected. Remember how the boolean operators are defined: `||` returns its first argument if it's true, the second argument otherwise; `&&` returns its first argument if it's false, the second argument otherwise. In other words, each returns the last operand that needed to be evaluated in order to determine the value of the expression. Therefore, if the second operand is an assignment it will be evaluated with `||` if the assignee is false, and with `&&` if true.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could consider doing something like this.

Implement `#to_time` on String and NilClass, perhaps in a `extensions.rb` (as recommended in [Ruby Best Practices](http://rubybestpractices.com/), e.g.

```
require 'time'
class String
  def to_time
    Time.parse(self) # add error/exception handling to taste
  end
end

class NilClass
  def to_time
    nil
  end
end
```

Then you can just call `params[:task][:created_at].to_time` and the duplication is gone.

I'm not at all sure that this necessarily constitutes "best practice", but IMHO it meets the objective of the question...

Answer (score 0):

I am not incredibly familiar with Ruby, but since it has Perl roots, there may be a construct that allows you to write it like this:

```
$_ = Time->parse($_) for params[:task][:completed_at] || ();
```

basically exploiting the for loop to create an alias to the variable, if it exists

maybe something like:

```
(params[:task][:completed_at] || ()).each { |i| i = Time.parse(i) }
```

edit:

I see that Ruby has an `alias` keyword. I am not familiar enough with it to give a Ruby example, but in Perl,  the above could also be written:

```
local *_ = \$params[$task][$completed_at];

$_ = Time->parse($_) if defined;
```

which specifies that `$_` will be an alias for `$params[$task][$completed_at]`

I tried playing around with it breifly in Ruby, but didn't see a way to alias an identifier, just global variables.

Comment: This won't work, because you'll get `NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass` when `:completed_at` is nil. Each is only available on an iterator class.

Comment: Replacing `()` with `{}` will eliminate the exception, but it doesn't overwrite the value of `:completed_at`.