# Is this a reasonable use for &&= in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

In [SO question 2068165](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068165/is-there-a-better-alternative-to-this-ruby-idiom) one answer raised the idea of using something like this:

```
params[:task][:completed_at] &&= Time.parse(params[:task][:completed_at])
```

as a DRYer way of saying

```
params[:task][:completed_at] = Time.parse(params[:task][:completed_at]) if params[:task][:completed_at]
```

where the params Hash would be coming from a (Rails/ActionView) form.

It's a kind of corollary to the well-known `||=` idiom, setting the value if the LHS is *not* nil/false.

Is using `&&=` like this actually a recognised Ruby idiom that I've somehow missed or have I just forgotten a more commonly-used idiom? It *is* getting rather late...

Comment: The parser does some weird stuff: a = 1 if a **works** and b = 1 if never **fails**

Comment: to add insult to injury if xxx; xxx=1; end **fails**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It ought to be. If nothing else, `params[:task]` is only evaluated once when using the `&&=` form.

To clarify:

```
params[:task][:completed_at] = params[:task][:completed_at] && ...
```

calls `[](:task)` on `params` twice, `[](:completed_at)` and `[]=(:completed_at)` once each on `params[:task]`.

```
params[:task][:completed_at] &&= ...
```

calls `[](:task)` on `params` once, and its value is stashed away for both the `[](:completed_at)` and `[]=(:completed_at)` calls.

---

Actual example describing what I'm trying to illustrate (based on Marc-Andre's example code; much thanks):

```
class X
  def get
    puts "get"
    @hash ||= {}
  end
end

irb(main):008:0> x = X.new
=> #<X:0x7f43c496b130>
irb(main):009:0> x.get
get
=> {}
irb(main):010:0> x.get[:foo] = 'foo'
get
=> "foo"
irb(main):011:0> x.get[:foo]
get
=> "foo"
irb(main):012:0> x.get[:foo] &&= 'bar'
get
=> "bar"
irb(main):013:0> x.get[:foo] = x.get[:foo] && 'bar'
get
get
=> "bar"
```

Note that using the "expanded" form causes "get" to be printed out twice, but using the compact form causes it to only be printed once.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Both forms are equivalent and params[:task][:completed_at] is evaluated twice (assuming its truthy) (see my answer).

Comment: I think I need to clarify what exactly I'm answering. :-P

Comment: I somehow wish you were right, but no, the [:task] getter will also get executed as many times in the &&= form as the 'if' form. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: I'll update my answer to show my counterexample, because I think your updated answer is still answering a different question to the one I'm answering. :-)

Comment: BTW: I'm not referring to the `Time.parse(params[:task][:completed_at])` function call; of course that generates an extra access. I'm only comparing how many accesses the `&&=` form makes versus the `= ... && ...` form.

Answer (score 1):

Using `&&=`, in the case of LHS is false, it is only being read once, but not being set. This should make it clearer ...

```
class Test
  def initialize(value)
    @v = value
  end
  def v=(value)
    puts "set"
    @v = value
  end
  def v
    puts "get=>#{@v}"
    @v
  end
end
t = Test.new(true)

t.v = t.v && true
puts '----'

t.v &&= true
puts '----'

t = Test.new(false) # lets make LHS false
t.v = t.v && true
puts '----'

t = Test.new(false) # lets make LHS false
t.v &&= true
```

The result:

```
get=>true
set
----
get=>true
set
----
get=>false
set
----
get=>false
```

Comment: When LHS is false, that's fine: we don't want to set it if it's not there, but we may need to convert/validate/parse it if it's present but not in the form we really want, e.g. where we get a date/time as a string and want to pass it to a model in the type it expects.